# Computational costs of typechanges/reassignments in python

Tags: python, computation-theory

In the past, I defined most often new names for new variables in python. Nevertheless, reusing names may sometimes come with cleaner code like in this example.

With new names:

```
this_path = "/home/maestroglanz/private/gump"
this_path_as_list = this_path.split("/")
this_path_cut = this_path_as_list[:-2]
this_path_reassembled = "/".join(this_path_cut)
print(this_path_reassembled)
```

Alternative with reusing names:

```
this_path = "/home/maestroglanz/private/gump"
this_path = this_path.split("/")
this_path = this_path[:-2]
this_path = "/".join(this_path)
print(this_path)
```

Both programs result in

/home/maestroglanz

The readability of the second one is better in my opinion, but this is individual preference. What I want to know is: Which of these code snippet is computationally more expensive or are they literally identical. I googled for computational costs and haven't found a lot so far.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "type change" - the `this_path` variable is a reference to some Python object and you just reassign it to a different object. So your question essentially boils down to cost of assignment versus cost of creating a new variable - which is most likely just about the same (or only a miniscule difference which should be irrelevant in practice)

Comment: @UnholySheep As the new object has to be created anyway, the effective costs are only the "binding" to the variable. So, costs can be neglected. I thought so, but wasn't sure, as I'm not familiar with python internals. Actually, if this is so, reusing the variables is better, as the memory of the previously referenced object can be freed.

Comment: They are identical. Note, though, that if you try to reuse names when the values *do* change types, tools like `mypy` will complain, and you essentially forced to use new variable names.

Comment: You could skip the intermediate variables completely with `this_path = "/".join(this_path.split("/")[:-2])`. This would save the marginal cost of binding and reloading the intermediate object.